# Unity bullet hell line pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to make more bullet hell patterns for my game, however, I am currently stuck with making a line pattern.

I'm wanting the pattern to make a line of bullets that are at different speeds to each other so the bullets spread from each other. I know I *could* make several prefabs with slightly different speeds but that's inefficient with space.

The way bullets are spawned is that their rotation is set and they move forward in that direction, however, I am unsure how to set the bullets speed from another class which determines the patterns.

Here is the patterns class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletPatternsModule : MonoBehaviour
{
    static ObjectPools objectPooler;

    void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPools.Instance;
    }

    public static void ShootArc(float ArcSize, int BulletAmount, string BulletName, Transform tf, float Offset)//All arcs are in angles, not radians
    {
        float angle = 0;
        angle = Offset;//Offset is to the left
        for (int i = 0; i < BulletAmount; i++)
        {
            float AngleStep = ArcSize / BulletAmount;//Gets the step size for arc
            angle += AngleStep;
            objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(BulletName, tf.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle));//Shoots the bullet
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator ShootArcEnum(float ArcSize, int BulletAmount, string BulletName, Transform tf, float Offset, float LengthOfTime, float WaitPeriod)//All arcs are in angles, not radians
    {
        float angle = 0;
        angle = Offset;//Offset is to the left
        for (int i = 0; i < BulletAmount; i++)
        {
            float AngleStep = ArcSize / BulletAmount;
            angle += AngleStep;
            objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(BulletName, tf.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitPeriod);
        }
    }
    //Not quite done yet, problem
    public static void ShootLine(float MinVel, float MaxVel, int BulletAmount, string BulletName, Transform tf, float angle)//All arcs are in angles, not radians
    {
        float Difference = MaxVel - MinVel / BulletAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < BulletAmount; i++)
        {
            objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(BulletName, tf.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle));//Shoots the bullet
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Bullet class

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletAI : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
{
    public Transform tf;
    
    private Vector2 Movement;

    public string BulletParticle;

    private float speedx;
    private float speedy;
    [Header("subtractive speed")]
    public bool ChangeAcc;
    public float AccX;
    public float AccY;
    public float AccMinX;
    public float AccMinY;
    [Header("sine wave movement")]
    public bool SineMove;
    public float SineAmp;
    public float SineFreq;
    [Header("Set up stuff")]
    public float speedxMem;
    public float speedyMem;
    private float BulletRot;
    private float ST;

    private int Length;

    public bool Specifics;
    public bool Killable;

    public string[] CollisionNames;

    ObjectPools objectPooler;

    void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPools.Instance;
        speedxMem = speedx;
        speedyMem = speedy;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void OnObjectSpawn()
    {
        if (DEBUG.ChangeGraphics == true)//CHanges sprite to toast
        {
            SpriteRenderer rend = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            rend.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Toast");
        }
        if (BulletParticle == null)
        {
            BulletParticle = "BulletHit";
        }
        speedx = speedxMem;
        speedy = speedyMem;
        Movement = new Vector2(speedx, speedy);
        ST = 0f;//Sine phase
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (Specifics == true)
        {
            Length = CollisionNames.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
            {
                if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag(CollisionNames[i]) && Killable)
                {
                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("BulletHit", tf.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Movement = new Vector2(speedx, speedy);
        
        if (ChangeAcc)
        {
            speedx -= AccX * Time.deltaTime;
            speedy -= AccY * Time.deltaTime;
            if (speedx <= -AccMinX || speedx >= AccMinX || speedy <= -AccMinY || speedy >= AccMinY)
            {
                objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(BulletParticle, tf.position, Quaternion.identity);
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        if (SineMove)
        {
            ST += Time.deltaTime;
            speedy = SineAmp * Mathf.Sin(ST * SineFreq);
        }

        if (tf.position.x > 25f || tf.position.x < -25f || tf.position.y > 15f || tf.position.x < -15f)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        tf.Translate(Movement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can't you just get the instance of the object you are using in your pool, then get the component of the BulletAI and set whatever field you want to? If you are already defining bullet patterns, then however you are deciding where to fire them, set varying speeds to get your desired outcome when passed in. Or is there an issue I am not seeing?

Comment: I've recently fixed the issue by using the method you have suggested, thank you for answering :]

Comment: Awesome! Glad you could figure it out using the comment.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code rather looks like `c#`.

Comment: @derHugo I thought by UnityScript it meant by Unity's use of C#, thanks for telling me where I was going wrong and in a nice way :]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by changing the speed of the bullet in the object pooler